# Is there a way to set variables at runtime in python

Tags: python

I am trying to set/unset some of the debug flags while my code is running. Below is the snippet of the function

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self,debugFlag):
        self.debugFlag = False
    def some_function()
        if self.debugFlag is True:
            print "Some debug logs"
```

Above is the code snippet. I want to set this debugFlag while my program is running and depends on the situation want to set/unset its value. Based on the current value of debugFlag it should print debug logs or not

How to do this in python

Explaining my problem again : Suppose I am having a script that takes 60 mins to run. I executed the script with debugFlag False. After 15 mins, I want to enable the debug logs. How can I do this without interrupting my execution.

Comment: Of course you can set variables at runtime. You can't set variables any time else.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you should generally not use the `is` operator for simple value comparisons. `if self.debugFlag == True:` or simply `if self.debugFlag:` is preferable.

Comment: @user2357112: How to do that

Comment: When that situation you want to change the flag occurs, just do `self.debugFlag = True`?

Comment: @Kevin **for booleans** `is` is actually fine while `==` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I think he meant something else by runtime... @Nitesh, did you mean you have a python script running and what to set/unset variables from outside the python enviroment that is running it?

Comment: @FynnBecker If by "fine" you mean "unlikely to cause unexpected behavior, since the two boolean values are singletons, so referential comparison is OK", I agree. If you mean it's stylistically acceptable, I disagree. PEP 8 describes `greeting is True` as _worse_ than `greeting == True`.

Comment: @Kevin by "fine" I mean the correct way to check if a variable is actually set to the `True` value rather than testing for truthiness. PEP8 explicitly states to not compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`. Hence I'm calling that an anti-pattern. Strictly enforcing PEP8 would however use neither of those and use `if var:`.

Comment: Ok, I agree that `x is True` is the correct way to check if x is referentially identical to True. But you almost never need to do that; I might even call it an antipattern.

Comment: @Kevin: I strongly disagree with PEP 8 there. `is True` is sometimes right, when you care about an object actually being the object `True`. `== True` is almost always semantically inappropriate. `1 == True`, but `2 != True`. It's not the test it looks like it's performing; it's an equality comparison against an integer with numeric value 1.

Comment: @DSLima90: Not outside but from same terminal. I use pytest to run my scripts. It takes one hour to run a script. I want to shuffle debugflag inbetween execution

Comment: @Nitesh, I think i see... I dont think you can do it the way you want, but see my answer for 
 one way to do it, maybe it suits your case.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self,debugFlag):
        self.debugFlag = False
    def some_function():
        if self.debugFlag is True:
            print "Some debug logs"
    def set_flag():
        self.debugFlag = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of self.debugFlag when a condition is met, yes.

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self,debugFlag):
        self.debugFlag = debugFlag # or omit that arg and always false
    def some_function(self): # Need self 
        if self.debugFlag:
            print "Some debug logs"
    def condition_setter(self):
        # Do some checks here then set debugflag to False
        self.debugFlag = False
```

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification of your class:

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self,debugFlag=False):
        self.debugFlag = debugFlag    # initialize the flag here or use default
    def some_function()
        if self.debugFlag is True:
            print "Some debug logs"
```

After you create the object you will be able to change its attributes, like:

```
obj_abc = ABC()        # debug off by default
obj_abc.some_function()    # no debug print

obj_abc.debugFlag = True   # enable debug
obj_abc.some_function()    # now with debug print

obj_abc.debugFlag = False  # disable debug
obj_abc.some_function()    # now without debug print
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to declare var in your modules root, and import/reference them in the same scope when you set and reference.

Imagine the directory structure of your modules like so

```
my_module/
- __init__.py
- another_module.py
- utils/
  - __init__.py
  - and_so_on.py
```

in my_module/__init__.py declare your __debug__ var

```
__debug__ = False
```

In your example code

```
import my_module
class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
      pass
    def some_function()
        if my_module.__debug__ is True:
            print "Some debug logs"
```

Then before you actually execute the code, set your debug flag to `False` importing and referencing in the same fashion

```
import my_module
my_module.__debug__ = True
```

As long as you import and reference the variable the same IE:

```
import my_module
if my_module.__debug__ is True:
   print("IN DEBUG")
```

It will retain its value throughout your execution

Comment: I want to change its value when i have executed my code. Suppose my script is taking an hour to execute. After 15 mins of execution I want to see the debug logs

Comment: It really depends on how your application executes (IE: Web application or daemon etc). But you could have a remote datasource set these variables, however each execution / iteration would need to check the datasource. What I demonstrated is essentially a convention for setting and referencing a flag throughout your application so you have a single reference point

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
class ABC():
     def __init__(self, debugFlag):
          self.debugFlag = debugFlag

     def some_function(self):
         if self.debugFlag:
               print('Debug on\n')
         else:
               print('Debug off\n')


abc_object = ABC(False)

def check_choice():
  if str(choice) == '1':
     abc_object.debugFlag = True
     abc_object.some_function()

  elif str(choice) == '2':
     abc_object.debugFlag = False
     abc_object.some_function()
  else :
     print('Invalid input')

while True:
    choice = input('Type 1 to enable debugging, 2 to disable debuigging : ')
    check_choice()
```

Summary:

When you initialize the class it takes 1 mandatory argument debugFlag, either True or False.

When you define a function from within the class you should use the 'self' argument.
[Explanation as to of why this is](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

'if self.debugFlag' is the same as if 'self.debugFlag is True :' The former should be used as it is more concise.

We instantiate an instance of ABC and store it in the variable abc_object. We pass it a default value for debugFlag, in this case False.

We then introduce some logic to check the state of debugFlag, and then perform some function based on the outcome of our logic.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this directly from variables, but you can, for example, create a file (debug.txt for example) and check if it exists for your triggering. For example, create an empty file called debug.txt and check, inside your script, if the file exists.

Untested code:

```
import os

class ABC:
    def __init__(self,debugFlag):
        self.debugFlag = False
    def some_function()
        if os.path.exists("debug.txt"):
            print "Some debug logs"
```

This way you can trigger/untrigger debug by creating/deleting the file "debug.txt".